# Instagram style camera transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Is there a way to create an *Instagram* style camera transition, where the current ViewController slides down to reveal the camera `ViewController` behind it? If so, how can I implement it, and make it work with the `UINavigationController` nav stack?

Answer (score 1):

Take a screenshot of your current view controller and present another view controller modally with that screenshot, create a UIImageView in the new view controller you presented, then dismiss the screenshot down revealing the contents of that view controller underneath